# How can a user with less than 2k reputation be allowed to review suggested edits?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

In the review queues page, I can see which users have most recently reviewed each type.

To review suggested edits, we need at least 2k reputation but I've seen users who have less than 2k reputation or in this post only 11 reputation appearing on this page as having done review tasks.

[image]

How could it be possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any user can approve an edit suggested on their own post.

This will count as a review.

Comment: Is this happened every time?

Comment: @Lnux this is the only way someone with <2k can complete a suggested edit review, yes, if that's what you're asking